# uninstall ipython mac os x

Tags: macos, ipython

I've just installed a new ipython 0.11 on Mac OS X from sources. Unfortunately it turned out that it lacks back-compatibility with its previous versions, so all the scripts I need do not work. 
After that i installed a 0.10 version of ipython from macports, hoping it would replace the current one (yep, maybe it wasn't a good idea - things gone even more complicated). But it didn't, and my scripts are still using the 0.11 version of ipython

The only thing I need is to make my scripts working. So I need somehow uninstall iPython v.0.11, or make version 0.10 a preferred to use

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pip uninstall ipython` might be able to remove it.

Otherwise, you'll have to find the files and delete them. At an interactive prompt, do:

```
>>> import IPython
>>> IPython
```

Which should show you where it's imported from.

Comment: You may also need to run `pip3 uninstall ipython` ...I found that I still had a copy of ipython lurking on my system after `pip uninstall ipython`

Answer (score 3):

Remember to run pip as a root, or:

```
    sudo pip uninstall ipython
```

Without sudo, it didn't work with me.

Comment: This means you're using the system Python. You should avoid that. Use a virtual environment normally, but first use homebrew to install a separate Python 2.x and Python 3.x in /usr/local/bin then set up via virtualenv for whatever you're really working on. They system Python should be avoided and should not be added to or updated. It's for the OS not for you. You should not normally need sudo with pip in these conditions. (I learned this the hard way)

Comment: Oh thanks! well, I assume the whole OS is for me :) 
Right, it means that ipython was installed under `/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages` which is a protected folder by default, that's why it needs admin permission. Where it should be installed somewhere like `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. To me, virtual env is not the best option when it comes to essential packages that must be available to Python always, anytime anywhere with any version. However, now my pip installations (for both python2 and python3) is under control.